# Power BI :: Get data through a REST API call with Bearer token

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, bearer-token, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to pull data from from the Azure REST API.

The endpoint I would like to query is the [Recommendations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/advisor/recommendations/list?view=rest-advisor-2023-01-01&tabs=HTTP&source=docs#code-try-0)

On order to do so I need:

- GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/f95326b6-759b-45c5-a123-ae6a9aa82754/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/recommendations?api-version=2023-01-01
- api-version: 2023-01-01

[image]

- Bearer token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIs...

[image]

And once I send it everything is fine and I have the results I want.

Now, is there a way to do the same in Power BI?

The goal is to have a daily refresh.

Also, Is there a way to create a logic that asks to the Azure REST API a new token?