Using the Power BI Authentication API returns accessToken null
I'm developing a custom visual for Power BI, and I'm trying to use the Authentication API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/authentication-api). I wrote this function:
const authenticate = () => {
    props.host.acquireAADTokenService.acquireAADTokenstatus().then((acquireTokenStatus) => {
      console.log('allowed?', acquireTokenStatus)
      if (acquireTokenStatus === powerbi.PrivilegeStatus.Allowed) {
        props.host.acquireAADTokenService
          .acquireAADToken()
          .then((acquireAADTokenResult: AcquireAADTokenResult) => {
            console.log('access token', acquireAADTokenResult)
            if (acquireAADTokenResult.accessToken) {
              getDatasetInfo(acquireAADTokenResult.accessToken, props.datasetId).then((createdDataset) =>
                setDataset(createdDataset),
              )
            }
          })
      }
    })
  }

It logs allowed? 0, meaning the privilege is allowed in the project, and then the accessToken is always null. I enabled the option of obtaining Entra ID tokens (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/admin/organizational-visuals#obtain-microsoft-entra-access-token). I also added the privileges to the project, with the url I configured in my Azure application
{
  "privileges": [
    {
      "name": "WebAccess",
      "essential": true,
      "parameters": ["*"]
    },
    {
      "name": "ExportContent",
      "essential": true
    },
    {
      "name": "AADAuthentication",
      "parameters": ["https://mywebsite.com"]
    }
  ],

I also added permissions in the Azure application Azure application permissions
From what I understood this should be working.
I tried adding localhost as a URI redirect.
URI redirect config
I also tried to make a request to get around using the Authentication API:
const myHeaders = new Headers()
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

const urlencoded = new URLSearchParams()
urlencoded.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials')
urlencoded.append('client_id', CLIENT_ID)
urlencoded.append('client_secret', CLIENT_SECRET)

fetch(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token`, {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow',
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Response status:', response.status)
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((result) => console.log('Result:', result))
  .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error))

But I get a 400. In Postman it works, so it's likely a CORS issue.
Since this is for a custom visual in Power BI, I also can't use MSAL because it requires popup/redirect permissions, which are not allowed in that context

Hi @Rodrigo, I'm in the same problem and someone suggested me a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78206371/power-bi-get-data-through-a-rest-api-call-with-bearer-token . I will update you if I have a grip on it.

@Rodrigo Pizarro  what code you used to get access token please share in the code

@Sampath the code to get the accessToken is the first block of code in the question. props.host comes from the visual implementation (simplified code below)

  private host: IVisualHost

  constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
    this.host = options.host
  }

  
  public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
        ReactDOM.render(
      <LLMChatbot
        options={options}
        host={this.host} />
  }
}```

@FrancescoMantovani thanks, I will try that, but I fear this will require a backend of our own to avoid CORS issues. We are trying to avoid backends if possible, and it seems like the Authentication API should provide that option

@ Rodrigo Pizarro add the CORS package and change the code accordingly. which scope did you use?

If I understand this correctly we can use App Registration to bypass the bearer token: https://www.cloudthat.com/resources/blog/a-guide-to-access-azure-portal-and-app-registration-using-rest-apis

@FrancescoMantovani I edited the question to include my tests with Postman

@RodrigoPizarro , read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78435496/how-to-connect-power-bi-to-microsoft-365-admin-center What data are you trying to retrieve?

@FrancescoMantovani I'm trying to get the accessToken so I can then query my datasets using DAX queries. The Power BI Authentication API should be working and providing the token. Alternatively I think I can make the REST requests with a custom backend avoiding the CORS issues, but we really want to avoid a backend

I faced the same issue and couldn't find a solution yet.
However, I found a work around using an oauth2 workflow within the visual.
Since the redirection to https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id> is allowed, you can use it to identify an AAD user.
The main issue is that this solution is blocked on desktop. And any redirection outside microsoftonline.com is blocked, so you can't use your own provider.

Can you use Azure Functions? It's in the end what I did to authenticate and retrieve the token. The authentication code I shared in the second part of the question can run in an Azure Function, so it bypasses the CORS issues. Not an ideal setup, but it does work
