How to connect Power BI to Microsoft 365 admin center
I was reading this amazing piece of documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis
My goal is to try to access the Microsoft 365 admin center and pull the list of our users, each one with their licenses:

The URL I have to point to is this: https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home#/users
But when I try to connect with Power BI I receive the error A web API key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided

But I'm providing the key that I've created in the documentation.
What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way to access the list of our Licenses?

Alternatively, you can make use of Microsoft Graph API to list users with their licenses.

@Sridevi , really? How?

Initially, register one Microsoft Entra application and add Reports.Read.All permission of Application type by granting consent like this:

You can generate access token using client credentials flow with below parameters via Postman:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Response:

Now, you can use this access token to call Microsoft Graph API for fetching users along with their licenses:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D7')
Authorization: Bearer <token>

Response:

In Power BI Desktop, you can create web connection by selecting Advanced and included Authorization header with Bearer token like this:

This pulled data with list of users along with their assigned licenses as below:

Reference:
Solved: Licenses and Users List from M365 connecting to P... - Microsoft Fabric Community by v-shex-msft

In picture 4: I can set the Bearer token but that will change right?

Thank you @Sridevi. the pictures are a bit in low quality. I just need to understand that thing about the Bearer and I'm done

I edited the images, please check if they are clear now. Kindly let me know where you are stuck. Have you generated bearer token via Postman as I mentioned in answer?

I will do it now. The problem is that the Bearer token expires after a few hours. So this solution might work for a few hours. I want to automate that so Power BI can refresh daily.

In that case, you can generate bearer token using delegated flows like authorization code flow by granting Reports.Read.All permission of Delegated type and offline_access to get refresh token. You can use that refresh token to get bearer token automatically.

Wait, this is too important for me, do you want me to open a new question about this offline_access? Because I don't know how to set this up

Yes, please post a new question and share the query link here by adding more details on your requirement.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Success @Sridevi. I was able to query. I had a problem because you need to grant admin privilege to the app. Now is good. Do you know how to implement an automation for the Bearer token?

Please post a new question with more details and comment that question link here

Here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78441484/power-bi-automate-bearer-token-retrieval thank you @Sridevi
