Power BI :: automate Bearer token retrieval
I posted a question and an angel helped me connect Power BI to Microsoft 365 admin center
But I now have a new question: the Bearer token will expire every now and then.
Is it possible for Power BI to:

Make a POST request and store the Bearer token in a variable
Make a Get request with the Bearer token taken in the previous step

